# Distributing a VFP application

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a VFP application which I distribute to my customers.  It is a compiled and linked program, **myprog.exe**.  When I distribute it, I have learned to also include in the folder these files :

gdiplus.fll, msvcr71.dll, vfp9r.dll, vfprenu.dll

This all works fine.  Is it possible to include these in the .exe program (I only distribute two .exe programs : **myinit.exe**, and **myprog.exe**)?

Thank you.  Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- sadly, you need the libraries as well.

Comment: @Andrew_46 - maybe you can mark as answered by clicked the little check under the 2 so this doesn't come up as an unanswered question again :)

Comment: Thanks, Missy. ( have done that).  Still learning about Stack Overflow. I'm trying to find a guide to this site;  on another question I am trying to find out how I can log in to look at my questions;  At present I can only look at this site by clicking on the emails which are generated when a reply has been sent.

Comment: Click on your reputation number and it will show you all your stuff.  If an answer is helpful, click on the little up arrow beside the comment like I did with yours yesterday and you will give reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

As Missy said, you have to distribute the libraries. What you can do is build a setup program, so that you don't have to think about what to include. A lot of VFP developers like InnoSetup: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php. You'll find help in using it for VFP applications starting here: http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~InnoSetup~Wiki.

Comment: Thank you Tamar.  I will check out InnoSetup